# after submit the contact form 7, it does not redirect to another page using javascript

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

i'm trying to post my contact form 7 (specific form )data to my another page using addEventListener but it does not working.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with JavaScript, you do not need an event listener though. Although perhaps it is easier to use this plug-in:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-success-page-redirects/

It adds another option to each created form to give you the ability to redirect to another WordPress page after the form submission. If you dislike installing a plug-in for it I could help you write some JavaScript code instead.